# Dojo function called in HTML

Tags: javascript, dojo

my html:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
          <script src="app/my.js"></script>
          <script>
                handleResult(<%server response data%>);
          </script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div id="data"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

my js:

```
require(["dojo/_base/Array"],function(Array){
     handleResult = function(data){
         Array.forEach(data,function(item,index){
               //Process the data
         });
     }
});
```

When the page loads call handleResult, I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

But I can get this function in firebug
window.handleResult
please help me .thank.

Comment: Works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97QKd/).

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use onclick, please.

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom"],function(dom) {
     var button = dom.byId("demo"));
     on(button, "click", function(evnt) {
         console.log(evnt);
     })
});
```

Comment: And the "test" function used in onClick is not in the right context and it is thus not found. By using the on event handling of dojo, the function actually **is** found, so this does solve you problem. Please use this.

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function is asynchronous. You cannot define a global variable from inside a require callback and then try to immediately access it. You should also never define globals to begin with, this is one of the basic tenets of AMD. Your application architecture is wrong and will never work. You need to use an AJAX call to request the “server response data” once the application is loaded on the client, and not try to do what you are doing.

Comment: NO. DO NOT use a synchronous Ajax call, ***EVER***. It completely hangs your UI. Fix your code to work properly with asynchronous operations.